# How to combine multiple csv into one file in serial manner using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am trying to merge multiple CSV file into one CSV file.

The CSV files are like

```
 Energy_and_Power_Day1.csv,     
 Energy_and_Power_Day2.csv, 
 Energy_and_Power_Day3.csv,      
  ....................., 
 Energy_and_Power_Day31.csv
```

I have used a small python script to concatenate the multiple CSV file.The script is doing it's job but it is not concatenate the files in serial manner.
It should take  `Energy_and_Power_Day1.csv` then  `Energy_and_Power_Day2.csv` then  `Energy_and_Power_Day3.csv` like this way.. but instead of this it takes randomly not in serially.
This is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import glob
import os

os.chdir("/home/mayukh/Downloads/Northam_bill_data")
results = pd.DataFrame([])
filelist = glob.glob("Energy_and_Power_Day*.csv")
#dfList=[]
for filename in filelist:
  print(filename)  
  namedf = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=0, index_col=0)
  results = results.append(namedf)

results.to_csv('Combinefile.csv')
```

The script is giving this output from `print(filename)` and combine these csv files in this manner.

```
Energy_and_Power_Day1.csv
Energy_and_Power_Day16.csv
Energy_and_Power_Day23.csv
Energy_and_Power_Day22.csv
Energy_and_Power_Day11.csv
Energy_and_Power_Day21.csv
Energy_and_Power_Day31.csv
Energy_and_Power_Day17.csv
Energy_and_Power_Day25.csv
Energy_and_Power_Day28.csv
Energy_and_Power_Day9.csv
Energy_and_Power_Day19.csv
Energy_and_Power_Day7.csv
Energy_and_Power_Day15.csv
Energy_and_Power_Day20.csv
Energy_and_Power_Day24.csv
Energy_and_Power_Day4.csv
Energy_and_Power_Day6.csv
Energy_and_Power_Day14.csv
Energy_and_Power_Day13.csv
Energy_and_Power_Day27.csv
Energy_and_Power_Day3.csv
Energy_and_Power_Day18.csv
Energy_and_Power_Day8.csv
Energy_and_Power_Day30.csv
Energy_and_Power_Day12.csv
Energy_and_Power_Day29.csv
Energy_and_Power_Day10.csv
Energy_and_Power_Day5.csv
Energy_and_Power_Day2.csv
Energy_and_Power_Day26.csv
```

My question is how or which way I can combine those CSV files serially?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not "random" (it would depend on how these files are organised by the underlying file system – [@tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48677856/how-to-combine-multiple-csv-into-one-file-in-serial-manner-using-python/48677994?noredirect=1#comment84354045_48677994)).

You can sort the filenames before you open the files. Use `list.sort` with a `key` parameter. Following this, you can use a list comprehension, and pass a list of dataframes to `pd.concat`. It *should* be more efficient than `DataFrame.append`.

```
import re

filelist = glob.glob("Energy_and_Power_Day*.csv")
filelist.sort(key=lambda x: int(re.search('\d+', x).group()))

df = pd.concat([
        pd.read_csv(f, skiprows=0, index_col=0) for f in filelist
     ],
     axis=0
)
```

Comment: It's certainly not lexicographic order either. How globs are expanded might be platform-dependent, too; but this is likely the order in whioh the matches are stored physically in the directory's internal data structure.

Comment: @COLDSPEED   Thanks for you answer. I have used your code to check whether it arrange all files in serially or not... `filelist = glob.glob("Energy_and_Power_Day*.csv")
filelist.sort(key=int(re.search('\d+').group(1)))
#dfList=[]
for filename in filelist:
  print(filename)`  but the python compiler giving me this error `
    `filelist.sort(key=int(re.search('\d+').group()))
TypeError: search() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'` I don't know about python re module can you help me how can I recover this error?

Comment: @Prayuktibid I'm sorry, that was a typo on my part. Please see my edit.

Comment: @tripleee Fair enough. Thanks for the comment, edited.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ A great Thanks for your help